# Запрет скролла над картами google

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api

Я видел подобные вопросы на этом ресурсе и на оригинальном и у меня все-равно проблема.

1. Для того что бы использовать `scrollwheel: false` нужно подключать google maps API, верно?
2. Что бы использовать Google Maps API нужно пойти на [сайт](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/) и нажать там получить ключ.
3. После получения ключа мы делаем это(и вставляем туда свой ключ):

   `<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap"></script>`
4. Пишем следующее:

   options = $.extend({
   scrollwheel: false,
   mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
   }, options);
   var map = new google.maps.Map($('contact-map'), options);

Во-первых. Обязательно подключать API что бы попросту выключить скролл?

Во-вторых вот так выглядит моя ошибка:

> Uncaught kc {message: "initMap is not a function", name:
>   "InvalidValueError", stack: "Error↵    at new kc
>   (https://maps.googleapis.com/m…jKzYQ8Di2M3T49Vxa_el_zFyw&callback=initMap:135:73"}

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Я не могу понять, bb-тег кода сломался? Почему код не выделяется правильно?

Answer (score 1):

> Во-первых. Обязательно подключать API что бы попросту выключить скролл?

Видимо, [обязательно](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/guide).

Вот пример встроенной карты без скролла. Взято [отсюда](https://codepen.io/status201/pen/wKowKz).

```js
  $('.map-container')
  .click(function() {
    $(this).find('iframe').addClass('clicked')})
  .mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).find('iframe').removeClass('clicked')
});
```

```css
.map-container {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 50px 0 3000px;
}
.map-container iframe {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  pointer-events: none;
  position: relative; /* IE needs a position other than static */
}
.map-container iframe.clicked {
  pointer-events: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="map-container">
  <iframe width="300" height="450" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?q=Status201%20Web%20Development&amp;key=AIzaSyCCGx7iveK21dme8OuLgX9Je7TUDDCw3_A"></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: Хм.. Полагаю через css и легче и правильней это сделать.

Comment: Ах да, это неправильное решение по причине что оно блокирует всю работу с картой. Смысл это делать? Я лучше тогда картинку загружу. Суть заблокировать колесико мыши поверх карты, что бы когда пользователь листал вниз карта случайно не оказалась под курсором и не пролисталась в неизвестном направлении..

Comment: По клику "разблокирует", после отведения "блокирует".
Можно прозрачный элемент сверху карты сделать, как вариант.

Comment: Нет, по клику тоже не подходит. Единственное что я вижу пока это параметр в API карт гугл и блокирование ивента колесика мышки при курсоре поверх карты. Как сделать первое я не знаю, а второе не факт что будет качественно работать.